# Backup Problem In Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: backup

When I'm Backing Up My Files Using the Backup Application, at the last time it shows a error that

> Could Not Backup The Following files make sure you are able to open them
>
> ```
> /home/neel/.cache/dconf
> /home/neel/.dbus
> ```

Answer (score 9):

It's a bug in Ubuntu backup (deja-dup). https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/deja-dup/+bug/1313034

You can adjust the rights of the folders.
Open a terminal and copy these commands:

```
sudo chown "$USER:$USER" ~/.cache/dconf ~/.gvfs
sudo chown -R "$USER:$USER" ~/.dbus
```

Comment: Adding the `~/.gvfs` in the first command doesn't matter, right? (That file is not found for Ubuntu 15.10.)

Comment: Still a Bug Dec 2018 Ubuntu 18.04 (deja-dup)......