# Back-up (Deja-Dup) Problem/Error-"Failed to backup some files" in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, permissions, backup, deja-dup

I know this has alredy been answered in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487362/backup-problem-in-ubuntu-14-04) & also [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346392/why-can-d%C3%A9j%C3%A0-dup-not-complete-the-backup-of-cache-dconf-and-gvfs)
My problem is this:

```
Could Not Backup The Following files make sure you are able to open them

/home/me/.cache/dconf
/home/me/.config/enchant
/home/me/.dbus
/home/me/.gvfs
```

So, my question is two-fold,
1. Is it required for me to "Back-up" above mentioned items ?
2. Does above mentioned files should have "my" (User) permission over "root" permission?

---

[ i.e. going by one of the solution given by @david-foerster, I should change the permission for 1 & 3rd item on list, but what about other two? ]

Thanks !

Comment: @Fabby, thanks i was of the same conclusion, but what is enchant file & gvfs? should i change ownership for them as well?

Comment: Sorry, i meant to leave a comment: Yes, do all. (replying from phone so not doing the search for you what the other ones are...)